# Mongodb converting double 250.0 to int 250 while saving data

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I am trying to save a decimal data from spring boot to mongo db . When i give suppose 250.6 the data is saved perfectly but when i give 250.0 the data is getting saved as 250.

How can i make sure that 250.0 is saved as 250.0 and not 250 ?

I have checked whether the conversion was done in spring but thats not the case as just befor saving the data is still 250.0 only in spring but in db its 250 of type int32 wheras 250.6 is double

Comment: 'How can i make sure that 250.0 is saved as 250.0' you can't. that is how mongodb works

Comment: Not sure if this is correctly closed as a duplicate. It is asking about Spring boot but the duplicate is about Node js